# How do in-memory unrandomizers (like in Cheat Engine) work?

Tags: random, integrity, reverse-engineering

Cheat Engine is a rather known memory editing and manipulation tool for Windows.

It has this feature to screw up your randomness generation, how does it achieve it?

My guess would be that it makes the initial conditions (like static noise, temperature microchanges and etc) artificially static and hence the PRNG fails to generate new values?

Comment: Making the PRNG seed static is one way. Another would be to simply replace/hook the random function so you can return what ever you want.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it, to figure out which one Cheat Engine is using ... you would most likely need to review the code: https://github.com/cheat-engine/cheat-engine/ there seems to be 63x references to the word random https://github.com/cheat-engine/cheat-engine/search?q=random